# Bind <a> href to Code Behind property

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, properties, hyperlink, code-behind

I want to set a public property in my code behind file, and then use that property to set the href property of several HtmlGenericControl `<a>` tags. Here is what I've tried:

Code behind:

```
public partial class className: System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
        private string _linkValue = "";
        public string linkValue {
            get { return _linkValue; }
        }

        protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             SetLink();
        }

        private void SetLink()
        {
             _linkValue = "myUrl";
        }
}
```

.aspx file

```
<ul>
     <li><a runat="server" href="<%= linkValue %>">Link 1</a></li>
     <li><a runat="server" href="<%= linkValue %>">Link 2</a></li>
     <li><a runat="server" href="<%= linkValue %>">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Instead of the href being set to "myUrl", the href is `%3C%25=%20linkValue%25%3E1`

Comment: I've always used the <% %> operators wrapped in a single-quote, not the double-quote.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @GarrisonNeely: Just tried it. It didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is all you want to do to those `<a>` tags, you don't need to make them server-side controls. Get rid of the `runat="server"` and it should work.